# How to populate a chart with data coming from API?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuex, vue-chartjs

I use `vue-chart.js` along with `Vue2` to create a chart. I have a problem with passing API data to a chart. I use `Vuex` store where I fetch data from API. There's a poor example on vue-chartjs.org showing how to handle an API. I also checked SO looking for an answer but in most cases `renderChart()` placed in `mounted()` is used, don't know if it's some workaround or proper way of dealing with this problem. I know that I need to pass Object instead of Array. I pass state directly to data , here `:data="allSales"`. This is my problematic code which throws errors:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Array

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="6">
        <Bar v-if="loaded"
          id="my-chart-id"
          :options="chartOptions"
          :data="allSales"/>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex';
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

  export default {

    components: {
      Bar
    },

    data() {
      return {
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true
      },
      loaded: false
      }
    },

    computed: {
      ...mapState('custom', ['allSales'])
    },

    methods: {
      ...mapActions('custom', ['getAllSalesAction']),
    },

    mounted() {   
      
      this.loaded = false
      try {
        this.getAllSalesAction()
        this.loaded = true
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
      }
    },

  }
</script>
```

**EDIT:** I add my Vuex store:

```
import axios from "axios";


const state = {
    allSales: [],
};

const mutations = {
    getAllSales: (state, all) => state.allSales = all, 

};

const actions = {
    async getAllSalesAction({commit})
    {       
        const response = await axios.get(`https://localhost:44327/api/Commission/allData`)
        commit('getAllSales', response.data)
    },
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
};
```

Basically I have 2 questions:

1. How properly populate chart with API data (using Vuex in my case)?
2. How can I choose specific column names from API and pass to a chart? Say I have 20 columns and just wanted to show 3 of them on a chart?

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , the store is missing while it's relevant

Comment: I added Vuex store. Actually, my store works fine and extract data from API, I checked it in console. However, I can't pass data properly to a chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read carefully the [documentation](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-local-data) and notice how the `data` prop of the `Bar` component is of type `Object` while you are feeding it with Array.

Follow the example from the documentation and use a Vuex getter instead of directly reading the state in order to generate the right data format:

```js
const getters = {
  getAllSales(state)
  {
    return {
      labels: [ 'January', 'February', 'March'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Data One',
          backgroundColor: '#F87979',
          data: state.allSales,
        }
      ]
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, it helps. However, I still don't really know how to pass specific columns to a chart. I tried this: `data: state.allSales[0].colName` and this is the only way I can get small portion of data and display on a chart. Just from one object. I don't know how to pass the whole `allStates`. If I knew how to do it I would be at home. Could you please give me some hint? Documentation doesn't say anything about it

Comment: What do you mean by `specific columns` ? This is a Bar chart - for each item in the `datasets.data` array a bar is plotted whose height is equal to the value in the corresponding `datasets.data` array item. If you have 3 items in the array - there will be 3 bars on the screen. If you have 7 items in the array - there will be seven bars on the screen.